# Best way to reference multiple (unknown number of) sprites in libgdx (Android)?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Im working on a game in which multiple "notes" (sprites) are generated.

The notes are created at random. Each of them has a random velocity and are created in a different thread. The Notes class is a child of the sprite class. It has 2 properties and 1 method:

- vel - a Velocity2 object holding the x and y component on the
  velocity of the note object
- pos - a Vector2 object holding the x and y coordinates of the note object.
- changepos() - a method that changes the position based on the velocity of the object

(I cannot post the code of that class due to privacy reasons)

I currently have a static class "NoteStack", which can hold up to 64 references to Notes objects.

```
public class NoteStack {
public Notes[] note_array;
public int stack_len;
public NoteStack(){
    note_array = new Notes[64];
    stack_len = 0;
}
public void push(Notes n){

    if(stack_len<64){
        note_array[stack_len] = n;
        stack_len++;
        Gdx.app.log("push", "pushed");
    }
}
public void delete_note(int pos){
    if(note_array[pos] != null){

        note_array[pos] = null;
        for(int i = pos; i<stack_len; i++){
            note_array[pos] = note_array[pos+1];
        }
        note_array[stack_len] = null;
        stack_len = stack_len - 1;
    }
}

}
```

Here's the code for my "update" function

```
public void update(float d, SpriteBatch b){
    core.draw(b);

    for(int i = 0; i< noteStack.stack_len; i++){
        Gdx.app.log("update", "Update function running" + i);
        noteStack.note_array[i].changePos(d);
        noteStack.note_array[i].draw(b);
        // scr_w - screen width , scr_h - screen height
        if(noteStack.note_array[i].pos.x > scr_w ||  noteStack.note_array[i].pos.x < 0 || noteStack.note_array[i].pos.y > scr_h || noteStack.note_array[i].pos.y < 0){
            noteStack.delete_note(i);

        }
    }

}
```

The issue (as you may see) is that whenever a note object from NoteStack gets removed (i.e. the delete_note method is called), other Notes objects in the array are affected.

Hence my question: What is the best way to reference multiple sprite (note) objects in LibGDX?

Comment: I don't see how other Notes objects are affected. The array that references them is affected. I do notice that whenever you delete one, you shift the indices of the array such that you skip the next one in your for loop. Also, multi-threading is almost certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking in programming, you should never implement own "classic" datastructures, only if it's really necessary and you can't use or extend a collection type, because the standard implementations are well programmed and tested, so those are safer to use.

In your case, I would use libGDX [Array](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html). That class has add, get, size methods, and if you really want to, you can extend the Array class to have an update function.

But in short, if you replace `public Notes[] note_array;` with `public Array<Notes> note_array = new Array<>(true, 64);` and use `get` and `remove` and `size` for iterating and managing the collection that should work.